# How can I fetch the logged user from back-office to front-office via an Axios call?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, authentication

I'm currently building a AirBnB replica as a final project for a Web Dev course.
I'm in a team and we're working on a front-office VueJS repo and back-office Laravel repo setup.
I'd like to set a button in the header in front-office that will have a button with text in it being "Login" if the user is not logged in back-office and "{{User->name}}" if the user is logged.

To do so I was built this function:

```
export function fetchLoggedUser(){
  axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/fetchLoggedUser/")
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
    store.loggedUser = response.data;
  })
}
```

which calls for this route in api.php in back-office:

```
Route::get("fetchLoggedUser", [ApartmentController::class, "fetchLoggedUser"]);
```

which points to this function in Api/ApartmentController:

```
public function fetchLoggedUser(Request $request){
  if (Auth::check()) {
    $userId = auth()->user()->id;
    $user = User::findOrFail($userId);
    
    return response()->json(["loggedUser" => $user]);
  } else {
    return response()->json(["message" => "User not authenticated", "user" => Auth::check()]);
  }
}
```

I've tried numerous edits and iteration of this last function in the ApartmentController but I never succeeded in catching the logged User, User->id or anything else related to it.
The call always returns the error message in the else condition, like so:
`Object { message: "User not authenticated", user: false }`

Seems like the `if (Auth::check())` condition never turns true but that's never the case in the normal ApartmentController which isn't located in the "Api/" folder.
I've also imported the related models and the Auth Facade:

```
use App\Models\Apartment;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

Would you suggest anything else?

Comment: 4 things (for now): 1) front-office = frontend, back-office = backend. 2) please use some code formatting, phpstorm and vscode (and Laravel pint) will help you with that. 3) double-check if your api uses something like sanctum. Sanctum has certain ways to get Authorization to make a call to the backend. 4) Auth::check is something you do after a user is logged in, so first you have to do Auth::attempt and things like that. Summary: make sure the user is logged in, vue can save that 'state' somewhere. Use Postman to check your api calls

Comment: @UnderDog Thanks for the reply. As for what you wrote: 1) I'm pretty sure Front-office refers to the publicly available an reachable front-side/end of your project and back-office to the private front-end where you administer the website content, much like a CMS website builder vs the website once published. 2) I'm using code formatters and apart from 1 code block where I had 4 spaces indentation I can't see any obvious formatting error. 3) I'd like to not use Sanctum but the api does come with a middleware route with Sanctum. 4) I know the user has to be logged for Auth::check to work, I was.

Answer (score 1):

When declaring the route which requires the authenticated user, use the ayrh middleware, for example:

```
Route::get(
    "fetchLoggedUser",
    [ApartmentController::class, "fetchLoggedUser"]
)->middleware('auth'); // Only logged in users can access this route
```

This will restrict the route being accessed by unauthenticated users. Otherwise, it'll redirect the user to the login page. If the user logged in then you may do something like this:

```
public function fetchLoggedUser(Request $request)
{
    // An unauthenticated user will never reach here
    return response()->json(["loggedUser" => Auth::user()]);
}
```